# C# How to get the Max and Min numerical values (both) from a variable

Tags: c#, variables, numbers, max, min

I have a **C#** code with the next situation

2 variables: `double qty1` and `double qty2` that are frequently receiving 2 different positive/negative numbers.

Then there is a variable `double currentResult` **that receives the sum of qty1 and qty2 (positive/negative numbers) and currentResult changes its value every time qty1 or qty2 receives new quantities**. The values of currentResult are not being stored anywhere, it is not needed because currentResult is just for display purposes only, so it is just displayed in a the screen being showed as actual information and done. Until this moment we are talking about displaying a simple sum result, so please don't focus your answer in this part because is not the important one.

Ok, **what I need is** to get 2 values from currentResult that changes frequently as new data comes from qty1 and/or qty2:

- The largest positive number (`double maxResult`) among all the numbers that currentResult has ever had, being up to date at the present time.
- The smallest negative number (`double minResult`) among all the numbers that currentResult has ever had, being up to date at the present time.

Let's give a random quick **example**: when the program starts, let's imagine the first result currentResult displays is 7, then -1, then 3, then -8, then 10, then -4, -11, 15... and it keeps updating its current value when it receives new data, then:

```
- I need **maxResult** first displays as its value the number 7, then the number 10 as new max number among all currentResult has had until now, then 15, and so on.

- I need **minResult** first displays as its value the number -1, then the number -8 as new min number among all currentResult has had until now, then -11 and so on.
```

Later, maybe I could need to store something like the 5 or n last values of maxResult/minResult, but for now, the main I need is their current (last) Max/Min values to remain visible in screen until arrives any new Max/Min number.

Here I use the word "display" to visually understand what I need as final result but **the main I need is the necessary code to obtain maxResult and minResult** because I haven't found a way to get this 2 values from a variable as described here.

Please note here we are not talking about a pre-defined list of numbers in which we need to find the Max and the Min numbers, no, here we need to base the results from the values of single variable (currentResult), working with the numerical values it has as time progresses.

Comment: Whenever `currentResult` changes, you should compare its value with `maxResult` and if `currentResult > maxResult` then do `maxResult = currentResult`. and also compare currentResult to minResult and if `currentResult < minResult` then `minResult =  currentResult`

Comment: Thank you for the ultra-fast reply @ChetanRanpariya. I have a very very short programming background. Could you please write the portion of code to do this? I don't know how to specify in the code how to initialize with the first `maxResult` and the fisrt `minResult` as they both start "empty", and after that then continue comparing with the next `currentResult`values... I have the basic logic about how it need to work but I can't find the way to translate it into code.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/5p9Fe1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System;
public class Program
{     
    static Random random = new Random();
    public static void Main()
    {       
        double maxResult = 0;
        double minResult = 0;
    
        for( var i = 0;i<5;i++)
        {
            double currentResult = GetCurrentResult();
    
            maxResult = Math.Max(maxResult, currentResult);
            minResult = Math.Min(minResult, currentResult);
            Console.WriteLine("Curent Result " + currentResult);
            Console.WriteLine("Max Result " + maxResult);
            Console.WriteLine("Min Result " + minResult);
        }
    }

    private static double GetCurrentResult()
    {
        double maxValue = 100d;
        double minValue = -100d;
        double sample = random.NextDouble();
        return (maxValue * sample) + (minValue * (1d - sample));
    }   
}
```

Comment: **you can't imagine** how much I appreciate you taking the time to write the code portion of your answer @ChetanRanpariya **:)** I will add it into the rest of the code, to make some tests, right now!

Comment: Thank you very much for taking your time to write an example with the printing process. With that example I could see and better understand how `Math.Max` and `Math.Min` work. Have a good day.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Math.Max(double) and Math.Min(double) functions to compute the values.

For example:

```
using System;

namespace YourApp
{
    class MaxMin
    {
        public double maxResult = Double.MinValue;
        public double minResult = Double.MaxValue;

        public void update(double currentResult)
        {
            maxResult = Math.Max(maxResult, currentResult);
            minResult = Math.Min(minResult, currentResult);
        }
    }
}
```

You can create a MaxMin object and call its update() method whenever there is a new assignment to currentResult and get the values from the maxResult and minResult members.

Or make the variables and method static if you don't want the overhead of the object or there is no convenient place to access it where currentResult is updated.

Comment: Thank you @cph and sorry for my lack of knowledge about my comment. After this portion of code you wrote here is needed a kind of **while** or **for** loop to do the updates you mention? and about `public double maxResult = Double.MinValue;` should not be `public double maxResult = Double.MaxValue;` with `Double.MaxValue` at the end, instead of `Double.MinValue`

Comment: @adiario if maxResult was initialized to `double.MaxValue` it would never change. Initializing it to `double.MinValue` guarantees that it will be updated the on the first update. The example might need some additional logic to hide the maxValue if it is negative if it should only show positive values.

Comment: You can initialize them both to 0.0 to avoid showing negative for max and positive for min.

Comment: To use it, you would first need to create an instance like maxMin = new (MaxMin); and then whereever currentResult is getting assigned its value, call maxMin.update(currentValue).   To get the display values, access maxMin.maxResult and maxMin.minResult;

Comment: @JonasH ohhhhh! ok, now I understand the logic better. I have a lot to learn and to improve, Thank you for the clarification. I'm new here and I **Never** hadn't seen an online community with this extremely so fast responses, just see how CPH and Chetan-Ranpariya wrote the portion of code in minutes. For me is gratefully **amazing** to see something like this.

Comment: @cph: Thank you much for your reply above. I first Accepted the answer from @Chetan-Ranpariya because with that one I could make some tests before to understand well how `Math.Max` and `Math.Min` work, but your answer is also perfectly valid, so it just is I see the system doesn't allow to put 2 answers as 'Accepted', but once again thank you because your asnwer worked perfectly too. Have a good day.